# Define 'Path' (URL) to one level above parent root

Tags: php, security, url, path

In reading various opinions on securing a PHP document containing database access information (to connect to the database), it's been suggested several times to place this PHP file outside of the root directory (above or at same level as root but not in the root directory). While this seems to make sense to me, I've not been able to find any reference to how to gain access to this file for my 'Include' statement. Up to this point I've used absolute pathnames (e.g., /root) but I haven't found how to describe a path outside of the web documents directory. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you for any help you can provide.

**Code Implementation #1** (suggestion from Professor Abronsius)

I am now running into something odd. The new 'include' works perfectly for the first query but the second - which is almost identical - fails. I am receiving an error ("ErrorException: Undefined variable: connection") at line 3179 (see below).

Here is the first query (this one works):

```
require_once 'mysqli_connect_sa.php';
$sql_query = "SELECT ...";
        $result = $connection->query($sql_query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        mysqli_close($connection);
```

Here is the code for the second (this one fails with error):

```
require_once 'mysqli_connect_sa.php';
    $sql_query = "SELECT ...";
    $result = $connection->query($sql_query); // Line 3179
    $logo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
```

I am not seeing any difference so I must be missing something here in how this approach is utilized? The error implies that "connection" is not defined but why would that also not be the case for the first query? Any help here will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: are both queries on the same page? Do you redefine `$connection` during runtime? Silly me though... you have called `mysqli_close($connection);`

Comment: Yes, I added the "mysqli_close($connection);" when I started getting the error. And, yes, both queries are on the same page (the second following the first).

Comment: On a whim I changed "require_once" to "include" for the second query and it worked. I have no idea why but I will now explore (unless you have any ideas). Thank you.

Comment: Still stymied ... "require" works but as soon as it is changed to "require_once", it errors out for the second (and now third) query. My reading over the last hour makes it seem that require_once is preferred but nothing I've read suggests a reason for why the "connection" is undefined. Anyone have a suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Once you have included the db connection ( using any of the methods `require`,`require_once`,`include` or `include_once` ) you do not need to include it again on that page/script. Do not close the connection if you plan to re-use the connection on that page... the connection will close, by default, when the page / script is finished.

Comment: I did try that and it did not work. I believe it's because each query is part of a separate PHP function - I believe that the connection is automatically closed after each return?

Comment: hold the front page! What? `"each query is part of a separate PHP function"` ? You would make life easier if you posted the code rather than unconnected extracts. If these queries are within your own functions either assign the globally create db connection as a parameter to the function or, from inside the function itself, call `global $connection;` - do not make/break/make connections unnecessarily

Comment: Looks like my lack of understanding here has wasted some of your time. I apologize. Thanks for your patience and your solution. Learning can be fun but not when you frustrate the "teacher" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps using `chdir` and `getcwd` will help

```
<?php
    
    $cwd=getcwd();  # current working directory...
    chdir( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] );
    
    chdir('../');   #go up 1 level
    define( 'PATH', getcwd() ); #define PATH
    
    chdir( $cwd );  #go back to original working directory
    
    echo PATH.'<br>';
?>
```

You can define the `includes_path` using a static string or you could use a method like above to determine the level above the document root and call:

```
set_include_path( PATH );
```

If there is a specific directory above root containing config files, db connections etc:

```
chdir('../conn/');
define( 'PATH', getcwd() );
set_include_path( PATH );
```

and then you should be able to include files using a simple call such as:

```
require 'db.php';
```

If you are using the db connection within your own functions then you again do not need to rebuild the connection for every invocation of your functions. A single connection will suffice if handled correctly. The following is pseudo-code.

```
require 'db.php';
$db=new db($usr,$pwd,$host,$db);


function userfunc_1($db){
    $sql='select * from table1';
    $res=$db->query($sql);
    return $res;
}
function userfunc_2($db){
    $sql='select * from table2';
    $res=$db->query($sql);
    return $res;
}

$a=userfunc_1($db);
$b=userfunc_2($db);
```

OR

```
require 'db.php';
$db=new db($usr,$pwd,$host,$db);


function userfunc_1(){
    global $db;
    $sql='select * from table1';
    $res=$db->query($sql);
    return $res;
}
function userfunc_2(){
    global $db;
    $sql='select * from table2';
    $res=$db->query($sql);
    return $res;
}

$a=userfunc_1();
$b=userfunc_2();
```

In both cases the same database connection is used but either passed as a parameter or included with `global`

Comment: Brilliant! Just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Quick follow-up: I have fully tested your suggestion and it works perfectly. Simple yet sophisticated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad that it helped - good luck with the remaining coding adventures

Comment: I just posted a problem I ran into (see original question). The included file works for the first use but fails on the second use. Would you have any thoughts? Much appreciated.

Comment: More than I could have hoped for. These two solutions help clarify where I was going wrong and how to correct. Thank you for all the support.